# Increasing redis key expiry on fetching that key data from redis cache

Tags: caching, redis, redis-cluster

We all know that redis cache has ttl timeouts for the cache. I would like to know if there is a provision in redis cache to increase the ttl for every key based on fetch of the data .
That means if the data is fetched from the redis for a key then automatically the ttl is increased.
Pls help me to get some info on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with Lua scripting: get val and TTL (in millisecond), increment TTL, set new TTL:

```
local key = KEYS[1]
local pttl_incr = ARGV[1]

local val = redis.call("get", key)
if not val then return nil end

local pttl = redis.call("pttl", key)
pttl = pttl + pttl_incr

redis.call("expire", key, pttl)

return val
```